# Design Pattern for three levels of variation - Probably Strategy

Tags: design-patterns, class-design, strategy-pattern

How can I design classes better adhering design patterns for the below scenario.

- There are different types **Reconciliations** processing happening.
- Each Reconciliations uses one or more Artifacts and producing one or
  more Artifacts as result.
- **Artifacts** can be of any file type such as **Excel or Text**, and
  different classes needed to read and write them accordingly.
- Artifacts belongs to certain category such as **Sales or Customer** etc and
  thus need to read and write them differently (**Content structure**).

What comes to my mind is that three levels of Strategy each for Reconciliation Types, Artifact File Types and Artifact Content Format. But I am not sure whether it is correct and if it is right how to connect them correctly.

Comment: Use FactoryMethod or SimpleFactory for object creation and Strategy pattern to change the behaviour of algorithm

Comment: Its really difficult to give a recommendation with such limited information and lack of context. What is likely to change on your design? And what is likely to not change?

Comment: @Ravindrababu Yeah that part I understand. But the problem here is that three different levels or types of Strategy is involved, for different processing algorithms, reading different file types (Excel, Txt), and different content formatting (Customer and Sales file content are different) of artifacts

Comment: @JavierIEH Everything in bold are likely to change and are candidates for Strategy

Comment: @Nicky When you say "Artifacts can be of any file type such as Excel or Text, and different classes needed to read and write them accordingly." do you mean that you need different libraries to access the contents, or that each file type has its own different steps to read and write them?

Comment: @JavierIEH Its actually both. First external libraries needed to read different file formats and then based on file content structure we need different steps to read and write them.

Comment: In absence of code snippet, It seems that File type processing algorithm (Excel or Strategy) is a Strategy pattern and Artifacts types like Sales Or Customer can be implementation of interface or abstract class and FactoryMethod/Simplefactory can be used to create a  particular type